# floating divs without overlap

Tags: html, css, css-float

I have 3 `<div>`s, and I need to put the second one on the right, so I used `#two {float:right;}`.

This is my [current result](http://i37.servimg.com/u/f37/11/89/27/52/11111110.jpg): `#one` on the left, `#two` on the right; both as intended. The problem is that `#three` floats up.

I tried to put `#one` and `#two` inside a separate div than `#three`, but the problem is still there.

This is my [expected result](http://i37.servimg.com/u/f37/11/89/27/52/33333310.jpg): the top of `#three` should be at the same vertical position as the bottom of `#two`.

Comment: please post your code

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/DrYgu/

Comment: explain what the result is supposed to be

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to clear the float (`#three { float:left; clear:both; }`), and you don't need the `<br>` after div 1.

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/trojansdestroy/DrYgu/2/) is a working fiddle.

Alternatively, you could skip adding CSS to div 3 entirely, and use:

```
<div id='one'>1</div>
<div id='two'>2</div>
<br clear="all">
<div id='three'>3</div>
```

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/trojansdestroy/DrYgu/3/) is that.

Comment: Fixed it, sorry about that.

Answer (score 2):

You can add a `clear:both` on your div3.

See [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/DrYgu/4)

Comment: Add div { float: left; } and on #three a clear: both; like : http://jsfiddle.net/DrYgu/

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you are trying to do

http://jsfiddle.net/DrYgu/

```
<div id="container">
    <div id='one'>1</div>
    <div id='three'>3</div>
</div>
<div id='two'>2</div>
<div class="clear"></div>

#container {
    width:60px;
    float:left;
}
#one, #two, #three {
    border:1px solid black;
    width:60px;
    height:100px;
    margin:2px;
    display:inline-block;
}
#two {
    height:185px;
    float:right;
}
.clear {
    clear:both;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add a container around div 1 and 3 and float left while div 2 can float right.

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="one">
    </div>
    <div id="three">
    </div>
</div>
<div id="two">
</div>  
 #two{
    float:right;
    height:180px;
    width:100px;
    border:1px solid blue;
}

#container{
    float:left;
    height:180px;
    border:1px solid green;
    width:100px;
}
```